# I am making android application and need help to choose which AWS we can use?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, project

i am making an android Application where user can upload Information and other user who need it they can search it and use this information. i am confused which Service should i have to use ? I am familiar with AWS but confused that which one will work efficiently in this and how can i make application real time interactive, so whenever one user post or upload any information, very other second if some user is searching for it so they will get that information directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

For uploading files, you'll probably want to use S3.

For just information/data, you want a database, in which case you have two options. The first, RDS, is the typical solution to storing data in an application. It allows you to manage a relational database. The second is DynamoDB. This is a NoSQL database solution, which you would use if you have really large volumes of data.

My guess is you'll want RDS, based on the information you've provided.

Comment: I am making an application for my final year Engineering project, application is just like JustDial & Olx, Where people can post Information like Room on rent & tiffin Service Etc, so i need solution that which Services do i need to use to make this work ? in my application people can post information & We will make it visible for other users so whenever they need any info.so they can search it ! hope you get my idea about project.

Comment: At minimum, you'll need the database to store all of the information provided by users. This would be RDS. You'll also want to have some sort of server hosted on an EC2 to interact with this database. In this server, you'll likely want to implement a REST API which you can interface with through your app to insert data or search for data.